# Using sed how to replace comma before a specific string

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a file `temp.txt`. Here I wanted to replace comma (`,`) with `||` between `Select` and `From` keywords.

```
select emp_name,
       emp_id,
       loc
from   emp_join ,
       emp_loc
where emp_join.id = emp_loc.id 
and  join_date > to_date('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')

UNION

select emp_name,
       emp_id,
       loc
from   emp_term,
       emp_loc
where  emp_term.id = emp_loc.id
and   term_date = to_date('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I am using the `sed` command

```
sed 's/,/||/g' temp.txt
```

but its replacing all comma in the file.

Is there a simple unix command that will allow me to do this? How to do it using `sed`?

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma command edited sed -e '/^select/,/loc/s/,/||/'

Comment: What does the `loc` do here?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '/^select/,/^from/s/,/||/' temp.txt
```

Comment: Rakesh, when I am executing the command given by you, its replacing all commas present in the file. Wanted to replace the comma between Select and From keyword only.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@admin:~# cat N | sed 's/\(.\+\)\,\(.\+\)/\1\|\|\2/g'
select emp_name,
       emp_id,
       loc
from   emp_join ,
       emp_loc
where emp_join.id = emp_loc.id 
and  join_date > to_date('2015-01-01'||'YYYY-MM-DD')

UNION

select emp_name,
       emp_id,
       loc
from   emp_term,
       emp_loc
where  emp_term.id = emp_loc.id
and   term_date = to_date('2015-01-01'||'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: When I am using the above command - cat temp.txt | sed 's/\(.\+\)\,\(.\+\)/\1\|\|\2/g' -  its replacing comma present in To_date function. join_date > to_date('2015-01-01'||'YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{\bselect\b.*?\bfrom\b}{$& =~ s/,/||/g}esig' < temp.txt
```

Would replace `,` with `||` between every `select` word and the next `from` word following it, case insensitively (so allowing both `from` and `From` for instance as in your question, but also `FROM`, `FrOm`...). We use the `\b` word boundary operators around those words, so it wouldn't match on the `from` in `fromage` for instance, but it would match in `from,age` or `from-age` or `"from"` as `,`, `-` and `"` are not *word characters*.